# How to fix HTTP Proxy error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I use **Android Studio** for develop android application! but when clone the project from **github**, show me this error :

```
Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
```

How to fix this problem and clone the project in Android Studio? Tnx all <3

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you also need to configure the [https settings](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Comment: `systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password` this user and password, is my pc account?